# gmail smtp exception in java play framework

Tags: java, email, playframework, smtp, gmail

I was reading about what is the best way about sending email through play framework (java). I have found this: https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer and I followed the instructions. I use gmail.

Here is what I added into application.conf:

```
play.mailer.host="smtp.gmail.com"
play.mailer.port=587
play.mailer.ssl=yes
play.mailer.tls=no
play.mailer.user="blabla@gmail.com"
play.mailer.password="blabla"
```

and here is my controller:

```
Email email = new Email();
        email.setSubject("Confirmation");
        email.setFrom("Mister FROM <test@gmail.com>");
        email.addTo("Miss TO <test2@gmail.com>");
        email.setBodyText("A text message");
        email.setBodyHtml("<html><body><p>An <b>html</b> message</p></body></html>");
        mailerClient.send(email);
```

Everything compiles with no problems, but when I run it I get this exception:

```
[EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:587] at  mailerClient.send(email);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the change the gmail configuration also .
like-
Go to your gmail account then in setting section go to the "Forwarding and POP/IMAP" tab then enable "Enable IMAP".

Hope this will help if you are sending the correct credential.

Comment: I enabled IMAP, since it was disabled before. But still the sam exception occurs.

Comment: use java mail API instead of this.
http://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-sending-email-using-java-mail-api
https://www.arclab.com/en/kb/email/list-of-smtp-and-imap-servers-mailserver-list.html

Comment: I managed to send email using apache commons, which uses java mail API. Thank you